# Testing AbortController Fails when it should pass

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, abortcontroller

I am running into an issue with testing an abortController in a fetch in a react component.

Here is my useEffect for the fetch:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const url = 'string'
        fetch(url, {signal:ammAbortController.signal})
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                if (!data || !data.result || !Array.isArray(data.result)) {
                    setData([]);
                    return;
                }
                const newData = data.result.map(data=>new Data(Data));
                setData(newData);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                // Don't throw error for fetch-aborts since they are intentional
                if (err.name === "AbortError"){return}
                console.error(err);
            }) ;
        // Cleanup function to cancel the request if our component doesn't need it anymore
        // Must use new anonymous function here to avoid "Illegal Invocation"
        return ()=>abortController.abort();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [trigger]);
```

And here is my test:

```
const renderComponent = async () => {
        await act(async() => {
            component = await render(
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Component runningTest={true}/>
                </BrowserRouter>
            );
        })
    };

    it.only('the fetch returns in the event there is an abort error', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(()=>{});
        global.fetch = url => {
            return Promise.reject({
                name: 'AbortError'
            });
        };
        await renderComponent();
        expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    });
```

I keep getting this error, which fails the test.

```
thrown: Object {
      "name": "AbortError",
    }

      at _getError (node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:442:18)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

I'm wondering if there is an issue with jest/circus, but I am too new to tell for sure.  If I change my expect to `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`, that also fails, so I am confident that the overall idea of the test is working!

Thank you!